# How can I run Perl test cases in Eclipse using EPIC?

Tags: perl, eclipse, testing, epic

I am using eclipse EPIC (Perl plug-in) to run my Perl scripts. The scripts are running fine. but I want group my scripts and run together at a go. How can I do this?

The scripts I am running are test cases. So basically it would be nice if I can take the results of each script and display them in table like fashion or write into a file all the results. How can I do this too?

And can I connect to remote host to run the scripts?

Comment: Don't post the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103453/how-can-i-run-perl-test-cases-in-eclipse-using-epic I would recommend you delete that post instead of waiting for it to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Use "external tool configuration" in eclipse and run the

prove -l

command from your workspace directory ( I assume all the modules are under lib/ ).

It is a Perl app, from Test::More that is the basic for all tests, and prints nice reports. I use it under Windows.

If you want also to check how to improve your tests use Devel::Cover, a very powerfull tool,

read this short article/how-to if you want

http://perl-node-interface.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-use-develcover.html

about how to use Devel::Cover on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, you can use a batch (.bat) file to run the scripts in groups. Create a testcase.bat file in your text editor and type the following lines in it:

```
perl script1.pl
perl script2.pl
perl script3.pl
```

where script1.pl, script2.pl and script3.pl are your script filenames.

Then run the testcase.bat file from your command line.

You will have to print your outputs from each script to a common file by opening a filehandle.
The 'append' mode ">>" will be useful here.